# What are the limitations of integrating React and Rails 2.3?

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails-2

Could you just use Webpack and Babel to transpile the code into the `/public` directory?  Is the asset pipeline necessary to do the integration and still have support for tools like React and Redux dev tools in Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

Could you just use Webpack and Babel to transpile the code into the /public directory? **Yes- you can.**

Is the asset pipeline necessary to do the integration and still have support for tools like React and Redux dev tools in Chrome? **YES**

ReactJs is just your view layer. It doesn't matter which backend tools or framework your using. Like in MVC- your ReactJS is the "V" view.